# Clear or Reset Button

Tags: html, forms, button, reset

I have a form and a working reset button. When i click the button all inputs and text area boxes are clear. I was wondering if there's a way to create a clear/reset button that will clear only some inputs and not what i have inside my text area box.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9T45A/) solution.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="clearit" /><br />
    <input type="text" class="clearit" /><br />
    <input type="text" class="clearit" /><br />
    <textarea id="t5"></textarea><br />
    <input type="reset" id="reset" />
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#reset').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.clearit').val("");
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much. cant seam to understand where should I place the JS code? in the head? body? as onclick?

Comment: Add just before closing the body tag. You can place it in head section too. Whatever you want to clear, add "clearit" class to it.

Comment: I think I have tried everything... i have added the ID to the button and the class to all inputs i want to clear besides the text erea which got a diffrent ID. i have tried to place the script in the head, body section like this: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reset').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.clearit').val("");
    });
    
});
</script> but nothing works...

Comment: Have you linked jquery to your webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Assign all input elements a class let suppose inputs and different ids let suppose the id of text area is text_area.

```
<input type  = "textarea " id = "textarea ">
```

Now with jquery

```
$(function(){
   $('.inputs').each(function()
   {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
         if(id == 'textarea '){

         }else{
           $(this).attr('value',"");
         }
   });
})
```

Done!

Comment: actually textareas are different tags: <textarea></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

use jquery it will help u , give the class to fields which u want to clear on click of button and give id to  your button

```
    $('#id_of_button').click(function(){
    $('.input_field_class').val("");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

See the link

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml

Basically rather than calling a form.reset() from the reset button, call an external function which clears out the fields you require and leave the remaining as it is.

Hope it solves your problem!