# Reset only 1 radio group with OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have a form that has several radio groups. There is one particular radio group that I want the user to be able to reset without resetting the entire form. I created a button whose value is Reset Participation Levels. Here is the function for the click event of that button:

```
<script>
function ParticipationReset(){
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_0').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_1').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_2').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_3').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_4').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_5').removeAttribute('disabled');   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_6').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('ExhibitorParticipaton_0').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('ExhibitorParticipaton_1').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_0').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_1').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_2').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_3').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_4').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_5').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('SponsorshipParticipaton_6').checked = false;   
document.getElementById('ExhibitorParticipaton_0').checked = false; 
document.getElementById('ExhibitorParticipaton_1').checked = false; 
}
</script>
```

However, when I click the button, all radio buttons in the form are reset even if they are not specified in the function. The link to the page is www.pfacmeeting.org/2016/exhibitorform.htm.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

cdr6545

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, should be .html, not .htm

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because the button is set as "reset" , for a particular reset, please change the line to:

```
<input type="button" name="ResetSponsor" id="ResetSponsor" value="Reset Sponsorship Participation" onclick="javascript:SponsorshipReset(this);" />
```

type="button"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384050/clear-or-reset-button - essentially your javascript is OK but you haven't taken account of the default behaviour of the "reset" button.  You could keep it as `type="reset"`, but then you'd need `.preventDefault()`…

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that. Now, it does not effect the other radio groups, but it is not resetting the option that was selected, just enabling the disabled fields. FYI, I have renamed the function ParticipationReset. Thanks,

Comment: I found your new issue, on your javascript you have: document.getElementById('ExhibitorParticipaton_0').checked... you are missing a letter on the name of the field, it should be ExhibitorParticipation_0

Comment: Chris...thank you so much. Sloppy on my part. I also found that most of the spellings were Participaton instead of Participation. All works great now. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, sometimes we try to find the errors in the complicated logic on the code, and they may be something than simple like mismatching. I am glad your code is working now. If you don't have more issues please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all of the radio buttons in a group with a simple for loop like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("SponsorshipParticipation");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
    elements[i].checked = false;
}
```

Or if you want to reset all radio button groups with a name ending in "Participation", you could change the first line to this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[name$='Participation']");
```

---

Here is an example of how you could implement the code I provided above:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetParticipation()" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function resetParticipation() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[name$='Participation']");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
        elements[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dhouty. But where would I put this code and what triggers it? How would I attach it to the onclick event?  Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an example of how you could implement the code I provided.